# How to create a data flow task using Oracle procedure to return data?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ssis

I have a SSIS package which uses Data Flow Task to connect with Oracle database to run a query for data and outputs that to a flat csv file. Now I need to convert this query to fetch data in an Oracle procedure and call this procedure from Data Flow Task. Someone created an Oracle procedure for me which basically returns a Cursor. Now 3 issues here:

1. I am Microsoft SQL expert but don't know much about Oracle.
2. When I run the procedure like this in PL/SQL window, it compiles OK but does not return any rows as you would expect in Microsoft SQL Server. Is that OK?

   > ```
   > DECLARE cur MyPackage.cursor_type;
   > BEGIN
   >   MyPackage.GetData(id => 1234, o_cur_out => cur);
   > END;
   > ```
3. In SSIS how do I call this procedure to fetch data? It has only 2 options "Table or View" & "SQL Command"?

Comment: "1.I am Microsoft SQL expert " - that's a big call! :)

Comment: @MitchWheat Well picked Mitch. But if you find out my knowledge about Oracle, in a comparative way, you will agree to this. :)

Answer (score 1):

When you run your block of code, it does not return any rows. However, it does return a `cursor` pointing to some rows which you can access using that cursor variable `cur` - it is an `OUT` parameter, meaning that the procedure sets its value and, when the procedure is finished, the `cur` cursor is ready for querying like this:

```
LOOP
  FETCH cur INTO your_variable1, your_variable2, ..., your_variableN;
  EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;

  -- process fetched values
END LOOP;
```

I'm not sure that a procedure returning a cursor OUT parameter will allow you to query data using SSIS, unfortunately I can't test it myself.

There is one possible solution I came up with, but it may be overdoing it. You could ask the person who wrote that procedure to write a `PIPELINED` function for you as well. Such a function can be used in the `FROM` clause of a query, and so you could create a view in Oracle database that would fetch data from that function, and in your SSIS package you would just query that view. Below is an example, also available at SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c66c7/1

```
CREATE TABLE emp (id NUMBER, name VARCHAR2(20));

INSERT INTO emp VALUES (1, 'John');
INSERT INTO emp VALUES (2, 'Jake');

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE emp_rec_t AS OBJECT (
  id NUMBER,
  name VARCHAR2(20)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE my_emp_array_t IS TABLE OF emp_rec_t;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_emp_ref_func(o_emp_cur OUT sys_refcursor)
IS
BEGIN
  OPEN o_emp_cur FOR 'SELECT id, name FROM emp';
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_emp_func RETURN my_emp_array_t PIPELINED
IS
  v_emp_cur sys_refcursor;
  v_id NUMBER;
  v_name VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
  my_emp_ref_func(v_emp_cur);

  LOOP
    FETCH v_emp_cur INTO v_id, v_name;
    EXIT WHEN v_emp_cur%NOTFOUND;

    PIPE ROW (emp_rec_t(v_id, v_name));
  END LOOP;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_emp_cur_view AS
  SELECT id, name
    FROM TABLE(my_emp_func)
;
```

Comment: That's also what I suggest. It's a good example too of how complicated the Oracle equivalent of a table valued function is.